# Tomato nutrition deficience

Tags: tomatoes

I am having one problem, i would be grateful if someone could give me a clue. The problem is as follows: my tomato low leaves are getting yellow and also showing tip burn, what could be the reason? Many thanks

[image]

Answer (score 1):

That might be a potassium deficiency. See [here](http://customers.hbci.com/~wenonah/min-def/tomatoes.htm) for photos of various tomato mineral deficiencies (potassium is about halfway down the page). A test of the soil in your container would be the best way to determine what's going on. If your plant(s) do have mineral issues, then I think it's very likely that they'll get one of the blights very soon due to decreased vigor.

Comment: Thank you very much Jurp. I also thought it could be potassium deficiency, however, i have been providing potassium through fertilizer XD